# This relay isn't allowed to send mail "From" gmail.com

Tags: spf, dkim, godaddy, dmarc

I'm on GoDaddy and since about January 2024, I've been getting this message from various gmail and yahoo accounts: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256 CV=yes: SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data: 550 5.2.0 p90jrnGxFJP3Fp90jrwJse xxx@gmail.com sender rejected. This relay isn't allowed to send mail "From" gmail.com

Note that I get the same message (I've changed where the email comes from) for yahoo as well.

I have the following SPF records defined for gmail:

```
CNAME qrtse7smpfeq gv-2nxlgpvpbukxpw.dv.googlehosted.com. 
CNAME selector1._domainkey selector1-corvettesnccc-org._domainkey.netorgft12813115.onmicrosoft.com. 
TXT @ v=spf1 +mx +a +ip4:208.109.215.239 include:secureserver.net ~all v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all 
TXT mail google-site-verification=eBbyvMHP6KFdq8LSW1BwRaxpwCg99gGUcob9JqlPLx0 selector2._domainkey selector2-corvettesnccc-org._domainkey.NETORGFT12813115.onmicrosoft.com 
TXT _dmarc v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:; ruf=mailto:; fo=1 TXT _dmarc v=DMARC1; p=policy; pct=100
```

What is happening is that an email comes into the server and is processed according to the forwarders list (this may process several times depending on the level of redirection e.g. a.gmail->b. ->c. ->d.gmail). The message comes in fine and when it is forwarded, that's when the above error occurs.

I'm not very experienced as to what the various settings do but I do know that what I have isn't working.

Comment: Simple/classical  e-mail forwarding tends to result in delivery failures  because it breaks the authentication chain. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Rewriting_Scheme  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_Received_Chain as possible solutions for that